# How to fetch super document's sub documents in CosmosDB?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

Consider that I have this simple container documented like that:

```
{
"Id": 1,
"name": "Parnet 1",
"childs": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

And we have child collection documented like that:

```
{
"Id": 1,
"name": "Child 1",
"ParentId": 1
}
```

when i return all parents with cosmosnaut:

```
var parents = _parent.Query().ToList();
```

I get this result:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "name": "Parnet 1",
    "childs": [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I fetch childs full data (like populate() method in nodejs mongoose) with Cosmonaut and EF Core so I can get result like that:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "name": "Parnet 1",
    "childs": [
      {
        "Id": 1,
        "name": "Child 1",
        "ParentId": 1
      },
      {
        "Id": 2,
        "name": "Child 2",
        "ParentId": 1
      },
      {
        "Id": 3,
        "name": "Child 3",
        "ParentId": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. What do you mean by "fetch childs full data"? All that you have are 3 numbers in an array. Is there other data somewhere else? If so, please edit your question to show that. As written, it's unclear what you're trying to achieve (or what you've tried, or what issues you're running into).

Comment: I modified it...

Comment: Ok, now please edit to include what you've tried. As written, it's a bit of data but no code and no specific issue - very open-ended. Also it's unclear where that child data is stored - maybe a separate collection, since the Id has been re-used? Maybe the same collection and the Id is actually stored in a differently-named property?

Comment: I think my question is clear now